# In iOS how to connect to Peripheral without scanning using the harware address

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, network-scan

How can we perform a `BLE GATTConnect` to a peripheral device in iOS without scanning (already knowing the hardware address of the peripheral device)?

I am more familiar with Android, knowing the solution in Android, I am looking for how above can be done in iOS. The above can be performed using the `BluetoothDevice object` which can be created using a `hardware address`. `Hardware address` can be obtained in any way by the application, not just be scanning.

In iOS `connectPeripheral` method of `CBCentralManager` requires a `CBPeripheral object` to make a connection to the `GATT server`. Instance of the `CBPeripheral` is returned for each advertisement seen by the central device.

In our iOS application,We know the `hardware address` (6 byte address in the advertisement) of peripheral and also know when the device is advertising ready to be connected.

Question:

> In iOS how do we connect with the peripheral without performing a scan knowing the hardware address of the peripheral?

Comment: I believe that you need to scan at least once to get the UUID that iOS creates.  Once you have the ID you can save that and use it with `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` to attempt to create a CBPeripheral - this may fail and you may need to resort to scanning

Answer (score 2):

I think that you will have to do a scan, but in the `didDiscoverPeripheral` CBCentralManager Delegate, you can check the Manufacturer Data field of the `advertisementData` for your 'address'

```
//CBCentralManager Delegate
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    //Pull the localName and manufacturing Data out of the advertising data
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    NSData   *mfgData   = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];

    //Now check for your 'address' in mfgData and connect if it matches.
 }
```